How can I trigger an animation with scroll up/down and do the full animation in framer motion?
I will go in deeper explanation, I have a classic button to activate a menu that expands and covers the entire screen and that is composed of a clipPath that is what expands and covers the entire screen and within this clipPath are the three typical stripes that becomes an X, so far so good in that part.
However I want that when the user scrolls down this button disappears along with the three stripes mentioned and that when you scroll up, this button appears.
I have the animations ready, but the problem comes when these are activated, mainly for the scroll up animation which is the one that makes the button appear.
Until the user or the scroll does not stop, the animation is not completed and my intention is that, if the user keeps scrolling down/up this does not influence the animation because I have already tested that if I make a quick scroll down for example, the animation is done more or less well.
I attach the code I have right now, thanks in advance.
MobNavBar.tsx ( The parent in this case )
//Missing the navigation part , check https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/framer-motion-side-menu-mx2rw?file=%2Fsrc%2FNavigation.tsx%3A19%2C15

import { AnimatePresence, AnimationControls, LayoutGroup, motion, MotionValue, useAnimation, useCycle, useMotionValue, useScroll } from "framer-motion";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { MenuToggle } from "../MenuToggle/MenuToggle";
import { sidebarVariants } from "./MnbVariants";

function MobNavBar() {
  //Variable to acces HTML tag
  var root: HTMLElement = document.documentElement;
  //Function to use more precise framer animation controls
  const sidebarControls: AnimationControls = useAnimation();
  //State for the toggling between the open and close menu
  const [isOpen, toggleOpen] = useCycle(false, true);
  /**State for handling the need of doing double click into the 
   * button to trigger the animation, for the moment it's the 
   * only solution
   */
  const [firstTime, setFirstTime] = useState(true);
  //State for store the window height
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(window.innerHeight);
  let { scrollY } = useScroll();
  let scrollYOnDirectionChange: React.MutableRefObject<number> = useRef(scrollY.get());
  let lastPixelsScrolled: React.MutableRefObject<number | undefined> = useRef();
  let lastScrollDirection: React.MutableRefObject<string | undefined> = useRef();
  let pixelsScrolled: MotionValue<number> = useMotionValue(0);

  const toggleValues = () => {
    if (firstTime) {
      sidebarControls.start('opened');
      root.classList.add('no-scroll');
      setFirstTime(false);
    } else {
      toggleOpen();
      if (isOpen) {
        sidebarControls.start('opened');
        root.classList.add('no-scroll');
      } else {
        sidebarControls.start('closed')
        root.classList.remove('no-scroll');
      }
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    sidebarControls.start('firstShow');
    const handleResizeHeightWindow = () => setHeight(window.innerHeight);
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResizeHeightWindow);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResizeHeightWindow);
      scrollY.on("change", latest => {
        let scrollYPrevious = scrollY.getPrevious();
        if (latest < 0) return;
        if (scrollYPrevious === undefined) return;
        let isScrollingDown = scrollYPrevious - latest < 0;
        let scrollDirection = isScrollingDown ? "down" : "up";
        let currentPixelsScrolled = pixelsScrolled.get();

        if (lastScrollDirection.current !== scrollDirection && lastPixelsScrolled !== undefined) {
          lastPixelsScrolled.current = currentPixelsScrolled;
          scrollYOnDirectionChange.current = latest;
        }

        if (isScrollingDown) {
          sidebarControls.start('hidde');
        } else {
          console.log('i enter')
          sidebarControls.start('show');
        }

        lastScrollDirection.current = scrollDirection;
        console.log()
      })
    }
  }, [height, scrollY])

  return (
    <LayoutGroup>
      <motion.nav
        initial="closed"
        animate={sidebarControls}
      >
        <AnimatePresence>
          <motion.div id="mobCircle" className="fixed z-20 left-0 top-0 bottom-0 w-screen backdrop-blur-xl  border-gradient border-gradient-full"
            key='cricle'
            initial="hidde"
            variants={sidebarVariants}
            animate={sidebarControls}
          />
          <MenuToggle toggle={() => toggleValues()} />
        </AnimatePresence>
      </motion.nav>
    </LayoutGroup>
  )
}

export default MobNavBar

MnbVariants.ts ( The variants of the parent )

export const sidebarVariants = {
    opened: (heightDim = 1000) => ({
        clipPath: `ellipse(${heightDim * 2 + 200}px ${heightDim * 2 + 200}px  at 50% 83vh)`,
        transition: {
            type: "spring",
            stiffness: 20,
            restDelta: 2
        }
    }),
    closed: {
        clipPath: `ellipse(30px 30px at 50% 83vh)`,
        transition: {
            type: "spring",
            stiffness: 400,
            damping: 40
        }
    },
    firstShow: {
        clipPath: `ellipse(30px 30px at 50% 83vh)`,
        transition: {
            duration: 0.6,
            when: "beforeChildren",
            staggerChildren: 0.2
        }
    },
    show: {
        clipPath: `ellipse(30px 30px at 50% 83vh)`,
        transition: {
            duration: 0.2,
            when: "beforeChildren",
            staggerChildren: 0.2
        }
    },
    hidde: {
        clipPath: `ellipse(0px 0px at 50% 83vh)`,
        transition: {
            duration: 0.2,
            when: "afterChildren"
        }
    }
}

MenuToggle.tsx ( The child in this case )
import { motion} from "framer-motion";
import { firstPath, buttonVariants } from "./ToggleVariants";
import { secondPath } from "./ToggleVariants";
import { thirdPath } from "./ToggleVariants";

interface MenuToggleProps {
    toggle: any,
}

export const MenuToggle = ({ toggle }: MenuToggleProps) => {

    /**Variants explanation:
     * Because the parent of this component MobNavBar, has variants with the same label
     * tags ( opened and closed), there is no need to repeat the procces of the parent 
     * in the child, it just needs variants with the same labels ( opened and closed)
     */



    return (
        <motion.button onClick={toggle} id="menuLines" className="fixed z-20 outline-none border-none cursor-pointer top-[79.5vh] left-[47.3vw] w-14 h-14 bg-transparent
        md:left-[48.5vw]"
        variants={buttonVariants}
        >
            <svg width="23" height="23" viewBox="0 0 23 23">
                <motion.path
                    fill="transparent"
                    strokeWidth="3"
                    stroke="hsl(0, 0%, 100%)"
                    strokeLinecap="round"
                    d="M 2 2.5 L 20 2.5"                    
                    variants={firstPath}
                />
                <motion.path
                    fill="transparent"
                    strokeWidth="3"
                    stroke="hsl(0, 0%, 100%)"
                    strokeLinecap="round"
                    d="M 2 9.423 L 20 9.423"
                    variants={secondPath}
                />
                <motion.path
                    fill="transparent"
                    strokeWidth="3"
                    stroke="hsl(0, 0%, 100%)"
                    strokeLinecap="round"
                    d="M 2 16.346 L 20 16.346"
                    variants={thirdPath}
                />
            </svg>
        </motion.button>
    )
};

ToggleVariants.ts ( The variants of the child )
export const buttonVariants = {
    show: {
        scale: 1,
        transition: {
            duration: 0.2
        }
    },
    hidde: {
        scale: 0,
        transition: {
            duration: 0.2
        }
    }, 
}

export const firstPath = {
    closed: {
        d:"M 2 2.5 L 20 2.5"
    },
    opened: {
        d: "M 3 16.5 L 17 2.5"
    }
}
export const secondPath = {
    closed: {
        opacity: 1,
        transition: {
            duration: 0.1
        }
    },
    opened: {
        opacity: 0,
        transition: {
            duration: 0.1
        }
    }
}
export const thirdPath = {
    closed: {
        d: "M 2 16.346 L 20 16.346" 
    },
    opened: {
        d: "M 3 2.5 L 17 16.346"
    }
}

I've tried to find a solution but I can't find a way to make the animations start only with the beginning of the scroll and not depend on you stopping scrolling.
